# Plotting multiple lift curves

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, lift, curve

I am new to R and trying to learn. I am trying to plot lift curves of multiple classifiers in one graph. I can't figure out a way to do it. I know the below two classifiers are essentially the same but they both give different graphs and I just want to combine the two. Below is the code I tried. Could someone please point me in the right direction

```
    fullmod = glm(Response ~ page_views_90d+win_visits+osx_visits+mc_1+mc_2+mc_3+mc_4+mc_5+mc_6+store_page+orders+orderlines+bookings+purchase, data=training, family=binomial)
summary(fullmod)
fullmod.results <- predict(fullmod, newdata = testing, type='response')
plotLift(fitted.results, test_data_full$class, cumulative = TRUE,col="orange", n.buckets = 5)

redmod1 = glm(Response ~ win_visits+osx_visits+mc_2+mc_4+mc_6+store_page+orders+orderlines+bookings+purchase, data=training, family=binomial)
redmod1.results <- predict(redmod1, newdata = testing, type = 'response')
plotLift(redmod1.results, test_data_full$class, cumulative = TRUE,col="orange", n.buckets = 5)

# Attempt to plot multiple classifiers
plotLift((redmod1.results, fullmod.results), test_data_full$class, cumulative = TRUE,col="orange", n.buckets = 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to plot multiple lift curves using the caret library. But first some data:

```
set.seed(1)
for_lift <- data.frame(Class = factor(rep(1:2, each = 50)),
                       model1 = sort(runif(100), decreasing = TRUE),
                       model2 = runif(100),
                       model3 = runif(100))
```

Here the `Class` column is the real classes
`model1` is the predicted probabilities by the first model and so on.

Now create a lift object from the data using:

```
library(caret)
lift_curve <- lift(Class ~ model1 + model2, data = for_lift)
```

and plot it

```
xyplot(lift_curve, auto.key = list(columns = 3))
```

[image]

If you would like to plot with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(lift_curve$data)+
  geom_line(aes(CumTestedPct, CumEventPct, color = liftModelVar))+
  xlab("% Samples tested")+
  ylab("% Samples found")+
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "method"))+
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = c(0, lift_curve$pct, 100, 0),
                                 y = c(0, 100, 100, 0)),
               aes(x = x, y = y), alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding. The one you've posted is a gains chart. I am trying to produce a lift chart. I can produce it with one model but I am not able to produce it with multiple models

Comment: Your are indeed correct. There are multiple definition's of the lift curve floating around. Could you please specify what you would like on the `x` and `y` axes?

Comment: Most likely you are looking for this: `ggplot(lift_curve$data)+
  geom_line(aes(CumTestedPct, lift, color = liftModelVar))`